# MySQL data rollback for past 3 queries

Tags: mysql, sql, backup, recovery

I just dropped my company's table and realized that the SQL backup I made was for STRUCTURE not DATA. I need to restore the data immediately.... is there anyway to do this? I'm using PHPMyAdmin and all i've done so far is

`DROP TABLE USEFUL_TABLE`
 AND
`CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS USEFUL_TABLE`
AND (IN DESPERATION)
`ROLLBACK`

Is there anyway to get the data records back?

### Edit

Thanks for the comments, and thank God above that I found an obscure backup somewhere that I was able to restore! Just as a tip for anyone as hasty and careless as myself, BEFORE any backup/export operations, **always make sure you've selected the** `Dump all rows` option when exporting data for a backup. I didn't, and I didn't even check to confirm that the SQL had the rows dumped.

Comment: Sorry, but I think, you're in there, deep... DDL can not be rolled back.. Oracle has a feature for avoiding this (FLASHBACK), but AFAIK, MySQL doesn't. Only chance you have now is if somebody (IT infrastructure) does have a backup, either of the DB files themselves, or proper backups of the DB...

Comment: Since you dropped the table, all its data was deleted automatically. Don't you have a backup somewhere? Can you perform a sytem restore on this computer/server, using the operating sytem tools?

Comment: @user961627 what tool did you use?

Comment: I was using PhpMyAdmin for the export... the obscure backup I found later on was a simple SQL file that happened to be saved somewhere on the hard disk 2 years ago.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DDL commands can't be rolled back in MySQL.  You need to restore from a backup.

If you need to recover data that was committed since the latest backup, perform [point in time recovery](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/point-in-time-recovery.html) with binary logs.  But this depends on having binary logging enabled, and having a continuous set of binary logs since the date of the last full backup.